# changing sender mail in signup cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel

I have a registration form taken from clevertech website like below, and it is sending mail verification to the new user and the user is receiving the mail and every thing working fine but: the user receiving a mail with sender as: my_username_cpanel@p3plcpnl0232.prod.phx3.secureserver.net

and I want it to send the mail from one of my E_mail Accounts like register@mysite.com instead.
below my PHP code.

```
<?php /* Registration process, inserts user info into the database 
and sends account confirmation email message */

// Set session variables to be used on profile.php page
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['first_name'] = $_POST['firstname'];
$_SESSION['last_name'] = $_POST['lastname'];

$_SESSION['City'] = $_POST['City'];
$_SESSION['Postal'] = $_POST['Postal'];

$_SESSION['Street'] = $_POST['Street'];
$_SESSION['buildingNo'] = $_POST['buildingNo'];

$_SESSION['phone'] = $_POST['phone'];
$_SESSION['noteadress'] = $_POST['noteadress'];


// Escape all $_POST variables to protect against SQL injections
$first_name = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$last_name = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['lastname']);

$City = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['City']);
$Postal = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['Postal']);

$Street = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['Street']);
$buildingNo = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['buildingNo']);

$phone = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['phone']);
$noteadress = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['noteadress']);

$email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password = $mysqli->escape_string(password_hash($_POST['password'], 
PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
$hash = $mysqli->escape_string( md5( rand(0,1000) ) );

// Check if user with that email already exists
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email='$email'") or die($mysqli->error());

// We know user email exists if the rows returned are more than 0
if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {

$_SESSION['message'] = 'User with this email already exists!';
header("location: error.php"); 
}
else { // Email doesn't already exist in a database, proceed...

// active is 0 by DEFAULT (no need to include it here)
$sql = "INSERT INTO customer (first_name, last_name, email, password, 
hash,Street,City,buildingNo,Noteadress,Postal,phone) " 
        . "VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$password', '$hash', 
'$Street','$City','$buildingNo','$Noteadress','$Postal','$phone')";

// Add user to the database
if ( $mysqli->query($sql) ){

    $_SESSION['active'] = 0; //0 until user activates their account with 
verify.php
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; // So we know the user has logged in
    $_SESSION['message'] =

             "Confirmation link has been sent to $email, please verify
             your account by clicking on the link in the message!";

    // Send registration confirmation link (verify.php)
    $to      = $email;
    $subject = 'Account Verification ( MereBuy.com )';
    $message_body = '
    Hello '.$first_name.',

    Thank you for signing up!

    Please click this link to activate your account:

    mywebsite.com/verify.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash;  

    mail( $to, $subject, $message_body );

    header("location: profile.php"); 

}

else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registration failed,Or first Name Exist!';
    header("location: error.php");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [additional_header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)s headers to your email,

This is typically used to add extra headers (From, Cc, and Bcc)

```
 $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
 $header .= 'From: YOUR Website Name <notifications@yourdomain.com>' . "\r\n";
```

Then

```
mail( $to, $subject, $message_body,$header);
```

Comment: Thank You Masivuye Cokile it is working as expected, still in the heading it is coming like: notifications@yourdomain.com  via p3plcpnl0732.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
but it is better than before.